# Spencer complex and de Rham Complex

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, cohomology, derham-cohomology

in those lectures notes written by Claude Sabbbah: https://perso.pages.math.cnrs.fr/users/claude.sabbah/livres/sabbah_nankai110705.pdf
there is the proposition 1.4.4 where he says that there is a functorial isomorphism between the Spencer complex and the de Rham complex. Does anyone have a reference to cite for the proof ?
It seems to be used like something common in several papers but I haven't been able to find a reference where it is proven yet.

Thanks in advance.